# Failure handling for GitHub Actions environment file set from command

Tags: github-actions

The following example shows a command used to set an environment file, using a command of `false` to simulate a command error situation that returns a non-zero exit code.

Is there a simpler way to fail the action for this failure scenario? Or a better technique when combining a call to a command that could fail whose output is needed for a later step?

```yaml
name: Failure in Command Test

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  test:
    steps:

      - name: Failure during env var set
        run: |
          echo "command_output=$(false)" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
          if [[ -z "$command_output" ]];then echo "::error ::Error calling command" && exit 1; fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `echo` command fails to write to the file in `$GITHUB_ENV`, it returns an exit code of 1. That would cause the `step` to return failure and the parent `job` to also complete with a failure. The lines of code after that would not run.

In your example, the subprocess -- `$(false)` -- fails and returns an exit code. However, that exit code is swallowed by the `echo`; it's just capturing the output. The `echo` step then writes the empty response to `$GITHUB_ENV`:

```
> cat $GITHUB_ENV
command_output=
```

`$GITHUB_ENV` only sets the environment values for subsequent steps, so that variable is not available for the `if`.

To get the error code from the subprocess, you can assign the output to a variable. If that subprocess fails, the exit code will be returned. A failure would halt the script automatically, while success would allow the script to continue to the next line.

The revised code:

```
command_output=$(false)
echo "command_output=${command_output}" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
```

In this case, you'll get an error from the `$(false)`. That will halt the script (and make the step and job fail). If the subprocess had finished successfully, the output would have been captured into the variable `command_output`, which is then expanded in the `echo`. It is then made available as an environment variable for future steps on that runner.